# Drawing circle of specified radius in meters using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, scale

I am trying to add a circle of a specified radius (let's say 200 meters) to a map. My thought is to create a SimpleMarkerSymbol object.  The constructor asks for a size of the symbol in pixels, but I don't know what functions are available to convert distance to pixels.

*E.g.,*

```
var sizeInPixels = //how do convert 200 meters to pixels???
var circleSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE,
  sizeInPixels,
  new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
  new dojo.Color("#0"), 1),
  new dojo.Color("#fff"));
```

Any insight?

Comment: Don't use a MarkerSymbol. Use a polygon which represents a circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, a circle marker symbol is used to symbolize a point, not an area.

When working in a projected coordinated system that uses meters, you can use the following to get the width of a pixel in meters:

```
var pxWidth = map.extent.getWidth() / map.width;
```

While the geometry service provides a more robust implementation, you can also draw circles client side with a center point and a radius. Here's a simple example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.5/js/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #controls, #feedback {
        position: absolute;
        height: 80px;
        font-family: arial;
        bottom: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        z-index: 40;
        background: #fff;
        color: #444;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
      }
      #controls {
        width: 440px;
        left: 10px;
      }
      #feedback {
        width: 200px;
        right: 10px;
      }
      h3 { margin: 0 0 5px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #444; }
      .label { display: inline-block; width: 140px; }
    </style>
    <script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };</script>
    <script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.5"></script>
    <script>
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
      dojo.require("esri.map");

      var map, sym, radius = 1000000; 
      // radius is in meters since the map is in web mercator
      function init() {
        var ext = new esri.geometry.Extent({"xmin":-5042425,"ymin":3604239,"xmax":8048485,"ymax":8584264,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}});
        map = new esri.Map("map",{ extent: ext });
        var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer");
        map.addLayer(basemap);

        sym = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([180, 0, 180, 0.25]));

        dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", function() {
          dojo.connect(dijit.byId("map"), "resize", map, map.resize);
          dojo.connect(map, "onClick", addCircle);
        });
      }

      function addCircle(e) {
        console.log("clicked the map: ", e);
        var pt, radius, circle, ring, pts, angle;

        pt = e.mapPoint;
        circle = new esri.geometry.Polygon(map.spatialReference);
        ring = []; // point that make up the circle
        pts = 40; // number of points on the circle
        angle = 360 / pts; // used to compute points on the circle
        for(var i = 1; i <= pts; i++) {
          // convert angle to raidans
          var radians = i * angle * Math.PI / 180;
          // add point to the circle
          ring.push([pt.x + radius * Math.cos(radians), pt.y + radius * Math.sin(radians)]);
        } 
        ring.push(ring[0]); // start point needs to == end point
        circle.addRing(ring);
        map.graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(circle, sym));
        console.log("added a graphic");
      }
      dojo.ready(init);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="tundra">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
         data-dojo-props="design:'headline',gutters:false"
         style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
      <div id="map"
           data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
           data-dojo-props="region:'center'">

        <div id="feedback">
          Click the map to add circles.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Derek Swingley, I followed the codes you provided above but the circle just wont show on the map. So you have any ideas?

Comment: @20Cents use this:  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/graphics_create_circles.html which was recently added to the API, no need to build circles by hand anymore

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the source data:

This will create a buffer of 100m and 200m on the ESRI base map with the ArcGIS Javascript API

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9" />
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples
      on iOS devices-->
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
  <title>Buffer</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.5/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.6" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("esri.map");
    dojo.require("esri.tasks.geometry");

    var map = null;
    var gsvc = null;

    function initialize() {
      map = new esri.Map("map");
      var layer = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
      map.addLayer(layer);
      map.setExtent(esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(new esri.geometry.Extent(-97.76, 32.32, -96.11, 33.42, new esri.SpatialReference({wkid: 4326}))));

      gsvc = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
      dojo.connect(map, "onClick", doBuffer);
    }

    function doBuffer(evt) {
      map.graphics.clear();
      var params = new esri.tasks.BufferParameters();
      params.geometries = [ evt.mapPoint ];

      //buffer in linear units such as meters, km, miles etc.
      params.distances = [ 0.1, 0.2 ];
      params.unit = esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_KILOMETER;
      params.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;

      gsvc.buffer(params, showBuffer);
    }

    function showBuffer(geometries) {

      var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(
        esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
        new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(
          esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
          new dojo.Color([0,0,255,0.65]), 2
        ),
        new dojo.Color([0,0,255,0.35])
      );

      dojo.forEach(geometries, function(geometry) {
        var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry,symbol);
        map.graphics.add(graphic);
      });
    }

    dojo.addOnLoad(initialize);
  </script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
  <b>Click a location on the map to buffer. Click again on another location to buffer again.</b>
  <div id="map" style="width:600px; height:400px; border:1px solid #000;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: This uses http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsap **=2.6**

Source:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/util/util_buffer.html